# DropDownList "has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items"

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a ASP.NET DropDownList, which I data-bind to a list of objects, and then it throws an exception. This error is driving me nuts, because the message is wrong, and the value clearly *does* exist in the list of items, as shown by the screenshot:
[image]

Here's the relevant ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlRequests" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="RequestNumber" DataValueField="RequestNumber">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: is it possible you have another item in your collection with the value of ""?

Comment: Not really. The only item in the collection is the one I declared in the ASP.NET markup.

Comment: Check your query and make sure the object you are binding has the right properties. Try this link, there is lot of people that had the same problem : http://forums.asp.net/t/1056921.aspx/6/10?+DropDownList1+has+a+SelectedValue+which+is+invalid+because+it+does+not+exist+in+the+list+of+items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be worth first databinding and then adding your blank value. Something along the lines of:

```
_ddlRequest.Datasource = request;
_ddlRequest.DataBind();
_ddlRequest.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
```

The only reason I suggest this is that I came across this before and after banging my head in frustration for a while just settled on doing it this way instead.

Comment: I ended up doing just that :)

Comment: I think it is because you specify a list item in the markup. This does not exist in the datasource because you add it in the markup. The above code by @Fishcake is a good way of adding that default value at the said index (0). You can then set it to be the default Selected Item and Value using _ddlRequest.SelectedIndex=0;

Comment: But this method cannot handle the case where the non-existent item is not an empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to clear data on `DropDownList`

```
_ddlRequest.Items.Clear()
```