# Dropdownlist has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. And Dropdownlist databind not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

What i am doing is clearing all the items of `dropdownlist` and adding 3 items to it. At first i encountered (refer title) error. I resolved the issue from these links: 
"[ASP.NET Web Forms DropDownList has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886179/asp-net-web-forms-dropdownlist-has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-d)"
"[DropDownList "has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704651/dropdownlist-has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does-not-exist-in)"
i.e 
made `dropdown.SelectedValue=null;` and
added databind() before adding items.
Now i am not getting any error but the items are not getting bound. . Here is my code:

```
ddl_org_type.Items.Clear();
ddl_org_type.SelectedValue = null;
ddl_org_type.DataBind();
ddl_org_type.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select","0"));
ddl_org_type.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Bangalore One", "B1"));
ddl_org_type.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("S1 Service Centre", "SC"));
ddl_org_type.SelectedIndex = 0;
ddl_org_type.DataBind();
```

But if i try to do this :
`ddl_org_type.SelectedValue = "0";` after binding the items, throws (title) error. I do not know where i am going wrong. I want to bind the items to the `dropdownlist`. Any help please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add all the items to Dictionary and bind it to drop down list

Example:

```
Dictionary <string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("Select","0");
dic.Add("Bangalore One", "B1");
dic.Add("S1 Service Centre", "SC");

ddl_org_type.DataSource = new BindingSource(dic, null);  
ddl_org_type.DisplayMember = "value";
ddl_org_type.ValueMember = "key";
```

Comment: Thank you @eranga. It worked. But i wonder why my code is not working.

Comment: try your code like this,                                                                                                          ddl_org_type.Items.Clear();
ddl_org_type.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select","0"));
ddl_org_type.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Bangalore One", "B1"));
ddl_org_type.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("S1 Service Centre", "SC"));
ddl_org_type.DataBind();                                              ddl_org_type.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: i tried everything. if i do as you say then dropdown does not take 0 as selectedindex but rather it will be -1.